How can I override border class with other border class?
I am trying to figure out how to override some table border classes I have added to my table.
I have created 5 classes for table borders, plus added border collapse. In the first row I want the first cell to not have borders, and the second and third cells to have only certain borders so they appear as one cell.  I could add !important to the none class, but let's assume I can't, and also assume that I cannot add any inline styles. And while I don't want to have to do this, I have even tried adding some classes like td.TBL {border-style:solid none solid solid;}and changing  class="T B L" to  class="TBL" but that doesn't work either.  So the issues I am having with the none class is similar.
What other options do I have to achieve this?


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.T>tbody>tr>td,
td.T {
  border-top-style: solid;
}

.R>tbody>tr>td,
td.R {
  border-right-style: solid;
}

.B>tbody>tr>td,
td.B {
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.L>tbody>tr>td,
td.L {
  border-left-style: solid;
}

td.none {
  border-style: none;
}
<table class="T R B L">
  <tr>
    <td class="none">
      1
    </td>
    <td class="T B L">
      2
    </td>
    <td class="T R B">
      3
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      4
    </td>
    <td>
      5
    </td>
    <td>
      6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




Protip: You won't make any more friends with one-letter class names than you would with one-letter variable names. Make them intuitive and semantic.

Is this for tabular data or structural layout? Why do you want multiple cells to appear as one? This seems like an XY question.

you are dealing with specificity problem here

You are overcomplicating matters.
Firstly, leave all borders in place and then remove only the ones necessary.
For example:


table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}

.R {
  border-right: none;
}

.L {
  border-left: none;
}
<table class="">
  <tr>
    <td class="R">
      1
    </td>
    <td class="L R">
      2
    </td>
    <td class="L">
      3
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      4
    </td>
    <td>
      5
    </td>
    <td>
      6
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




I like this. And if I have a bunch of other tables that I dont want borders on, I suppose I can make a class like so: .none>tbody>tr>td {border-style: none;} to add to those tables.
